# TextView in android widget doesn't update

Tags: android, widget

The TextView in my widgetis set correctly with the correct info when it's getting placed at the home screen. But when I update the info in the main app, the widget still shows the old info.

Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".WidgetProvider" android:label="@string/app_name" android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>

    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/widget" />
</receiver>
```

WidgetProvider.java:

```
package com.example.huskeliste;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int widgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

            DBAdapter info = new DBAdapter(context);

            info.open();
            String data = info.getTextViewData();
            info.close();

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, Main.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.loWidget, pendingIntent);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.txtView, data);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(widgetId, views);
        }
    }
}
```

res - widget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="1800000">
</appwidget-provider>
```

layout - widget.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/loWidget"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/background">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:text="" />
</LinearLayout>
```

background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient android:startColor="#CC111111" android:endColor="#CC111111" android:angle="0" />
    <padding android:left="4dp" android:top="1dp" android:right="4dp" android:bottom="1dp" />
    <corners android:radius="3dp" />
</shape>
```

getTextViewData() from DBAdapter.java:

```
public String getTextViewData() {
    String[] columns = new String[] { KEY_NAME };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    String result = "";

    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext()) {           
        if (result.length() > 0) {
            result += ", ";
        }

        result += c.getString(0);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Anyone have a clue what's missing in my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set an update interval in milliseconds inside your Widget provider XML. [Example code](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#MetaData):

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="72dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:previewImage="@drawable/preview"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/example_appwidget"
    android:configure="com.example.android.ExampleAppWidgetConfigure" 
    android:resizeMode="horizontal|vertical"
    android:widgetCategory="home_screen|keyguard"
    android:initialKeyguardLayout="@layout/example_keyguard">
</appwidget-provider>
```

However, you should know that the system does not guarantee the widget to be updated as often. Also, if you want the widget to update more often (e.g. after a configuration change, as it is with your question), you need to do it manually. Here's how I proceed:

In this example my Widget class is simply called Widget.class:

```
public class Widget extends AppWidgetProvider {

    // TODO: Don't forget to override the onUpdate method also

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals("update_widget")) {
            // Manual or automatic widget update started

            RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget);

            // Update text, images, whatever - here
            remoteViews.setTextViewText(R.id.yourTextID, "My updated text");

            // Trigger widget layout update
            AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).updateAppWidget(
                    new ComponentName(context, Widget.class), remoteViews);
        }
    }

}
```

Make sure to replace the layout and the `TextView` with references to your widget layout.

Then whenever you want to update your widget (e.g. in the `onPause` method of your main activity or whenever a Save button is clicked), you call a `PendingIntent`:

```
Intent updateWidget = new Intent(context, Widget.class); // Widget.class is your widget class
updateWidget.setAction("update_widget");
PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, updateWidget, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
pending.send();
```

Comment: Thanks for fast answere. In Main.java the "context" in Intent updateWidget = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class); is empty. What should I set context to?

Comment: context is marked with "context cannot be resolved to a variable".

Comment: That is your Activity context. You can use `getBaseContext()` or `this` there.

Comment: After I added the onReceiver, the onUpdate doesn't seem to work. It doesn't update when I add the widget or after restarting the device. Any suggestions for what can be the problem?

Comment: You can use AlarmManager inside `onUpdate` to schedule and send a `PendingIntent` using the same structure as in my answer every few minutes/seconds/hours. Be careful though, because continuous updating may drain the battery quickly. Use something realistic for minimum update intervals such as 15 minutes.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is my problem. The first code I had updated the widget on adding it and restarting device/phone. But bot on changes. When I added your code, it updates on change, but now it don't update on add or restart of device/phone.

I'm not shore how to past the code as comment, but the code inside onUpdate is pretty much the same as in onReceive. But with other variable names.

Comment: If I comment out (using /* */) the onReceive function, the onUpdate function works again.

Comment: Fixed it with "super.onReceive(context, intent);" in the onReceiver :)

Answer (score 0):

For future reference;

if you want to update data on the widget, call

```
appWidgetManager.updateAppWidgetOptions(appWidgetId,newOps);
```

where you call AppWidgetManager in your configuration activity.
and override `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged` method in your AppWidgetProvider class to get newOptions and run your logic

whole answer is on the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73560387/9346859)